# iterating though files in extracted directories and running an exe against the file with parameters

Tags: bash

Ok, so here is what I am trying to do - I have a bunch of archives that are named:

```
newnslog.0.tar.gz
newnslog.1.tar.gz
newnslog.2.tar.gz 
newnslog.3.tar.gz
newnslog.4.tar.gz
.
.
.
```

once each is extracted, I want to iterate through all the files in that directory and run an exe against the data in the file.

```
#extract:
tar -xzf newnslog.58.tar.gz
#cd:
cd newnslog.59 < yes the filename in the archive may be 1 more or less or the same as it is a continuation
#ls:
newnslog.ppe.0  newnslog.ppe.1  newnslog.ppe.2
#execute nsc2e with parameters against each file:
# ../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K newnslog.ppe.0 -f ../nsc2e.conf
```

I am trying a for - do loop but I must be doing something wrong:

```
root@VPX-13# for f in *; do '../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K "$f" -f ../ns2ce.conf'; done
-bash: ../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K "$f" -f ../ns2ce.conf: No such file or directory
-bash: ../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K "$f" -f ../ns2ce.conf: No such file or directory
-bash: ../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K "$f" -f ../ns2ce.conf: No such file or directory
```

I also know there must be a streamlined way to do everything including the extraction - something like:

```
find newnslog* -prune -type d | while IFS= read -r d; do 
    cd "$d"
    for f in *; do '../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K "$f" -f ../ns2ce.conf'; done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropping the quotes around the command as per [ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu)'s comment:

```bsh
for f in *; do ../nsc2e -c /netscaler/nsconmsg -K "$f" -f ../ns2ce.conf; done
```

... solved the issue.